# How to make For Loop Real Time in PHP

Tags: php, loops, real-time

I want to Make a Script which give result realtime .

In My Script it have 3 steps .

1st step was to grab all links from a webpage .(i use pregmatch_all function coz all links i need are started with same domain http://example.com/docs/* and grab from http://test.com/page/* )

2nd step i have to grab direct link from all links (like htp://files.example.com/files/* from 
http://example.com/docs/* )

3rd step Upload that file to and third party site and get the upload link from there .

lastly i added a function named which get the page ranges (like '1|5' ) so script upload all links from http://test.com/page/1/ to  http://test.com/page/5/ .

I have done the scipt it was alo running ok but it shows result after all completed but i want a realtime  result like script have grabed one link and do all steps with it and show that reult link on browser and then so on i mean a realtime solution .

How can i do that i used for loop but no real time result .

Comment: I really can't understand the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Flush()](http://ru.php.net/flush) would help you.

Answer (score 1):

use ajax. (run script in background and poll for current state)

http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/

http://api.jquery.com/get

Answer (score 0):

Reading up on output buffering, output flushing and related topics is definitely a good idea if you are serious about PHP web development.