# real time output in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make For Loop Real Time in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763796/how-to-make-for-loop-real-time-in-php)

I think when we run php script,web server wait until end of script and after that will return output. for example if following script doesn't have output.

```
set_time_limit(0);
$i = 0;
while(1) {
    $i++;
    if ($i%10 == 0)
        echo 'Salam';
}
```

How can I have real time output?I mean the script is not ended yet,but it echoed somethings.

Comment: Have you tried flushing `STDOUT`?  Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php).

Answer (score 2):

Call [`flush`](http://php.net/flush) when you want the current output to be displayed. If you are using output buffering, you also need to call [`ob_flush`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php).